# FTP Shell Script mkdir issue

Tags: bash, ftp

I am using the Bash FTP command to ftp files, however i have a problem where i try to create a directory that is more than 2 folders deep. It works if i use two folders deep but if i go to three folders deep then it fails. For example:

```
mkdir foo/bar - this works
mkdir foo/bar/baz - this fails
```

I have also tried this:

```
mkdir -p foo/bar/baz - which didn't work, it ended up creating a '-p' directory
```

The shell script i am trying to run is actually quite simple but as you can see the directory structure is 3 folders deep and it fails to create the required folders:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY="foo/bar/baz"
FILE="test.pdf"         
HOST="testserver"           
USER="test"         
PASS="test"         

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASS
mkdir $DIRECTORY
cd $DIRECTORY
binary
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Comment: Bash has no `ftp` command - `ftp` is an external utility and it's very insecure. Use something else such as `sftp`.

Comment: Do you have an example of how sftp could be used instead of ftp? Can i still specify the username and password in the same way?

Comment: No, you should use a key file. By the way, `sftp` is also an external utility. See `man sftp`.

Comment: are you certain i can specify directories more than 3 folders deep with this `sftp` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

mkdir under ftp is implemented by the ftp server, not by calling /bin/mkdir no such options as -p, 
what you should do is

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
mkdir bar
cd bar
mkdir baz
cd baz
```

If you still want your original construct, you can also do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
    local r
    local a
    r="$@"
    while [[ "$r" != "$a" ]] ; do
        a=${r%%/*}
        echo "mkdir $a"
        echo "cd $a"
        r=${r#*/}
    done
}
DIRECTORY="foo/bar/baz"
FILE="test.pdf"         
HOST="testserver"           
USER="test"         
PASS="test"         

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASS
$(foo "$DIRECTORY")
binary
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Comment: yea i know that would work but when I pass the directory segments in as a parameter it makes this method very impractical especially when i have file paths of varying lengths.

Comment: pizza is right. 99% of Ftp client/servers don't support what you want. There's no way around it. Sorry. However, there are dozens of ftp clients. you might find that one that supports the `-p` option, but if you're doing this in a commercial environment, you probably can't get permission to install that client into your system. Not to mention the time you'll spend looking for it. ..... `for loop` is your friend. good luck.

Comment: Yea thanks guys, i have resorted to using a `for loop`...and gradually building up the current working directory as i go.

Answer (score 1):

Try lftp instead:

```
[dong@idc1-server1 ~]$ lftp sftp://idc1-server2
lftp idc1-server2:~> ls
drwxr-xr-x    3 dong     dong         4096 Jun 16 09:11 .
drwxr-xr-x   18 root     root         4096 Apr  1 22:25 ..
-rw-------    1 dong     dong          116 Jun 16 09:28 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--    1 dong     dong           18 Oct 16  2013 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--    1 dong     dong          176 Oct 16  2013 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--    1 dong     dong          124 Oct 16  2013 .bashrc
drwx------    2 dong     dong         4096 Jul 24  2014 .ssh

lftp idc1-server2:~> mkdir a/b/c/d
mkdir: Access failed: No such file (a/b/c/d)

lftp idc1-server2:~> mkdir -p a/b/c/d
mkdir ok, `a/b/c/d' created
```